# Nutch how to crawl all links from one website?

Tags: solr, nutch

for now i use the follow commands to crawl a website:

```
 bin/nutch generate -topN 20
 bin/nutch fetch -all
 bin/nutch parse -all
 bin/nutch updatedb
```

but with this method it takes ages before i have all links from that website. I want to crawl one website and get all the links.

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`bin/nutch crawl` is the command you are looking for